# Form gets freezed during loading data in a seperate thread

Tags: multithreading, http, thread-safety, c++builder, indy

I use TIdHTTP component to load xml data from a bank in a seperate thread but my form is getting freezed during that time...

what could be the problem ?

I have a main form and thread class, in thread class i have a method called loadData and on thread::Execute i Synchronize(loadData);

when button gets clicked I created the instance of thread class like testThread *t=new testThread(false);

and that's all

when i click the button the main form freezes?
even seperate thread didn't help????

Please help!!!

Answer (score 0):

`Synchronize()` is running your `loadData()` method in the context of the main thread, not in the context of your worker thread.  That is why your main thread blocks while `loadData()` is busy.  You are misusing `Synchronize()`, rendering your thread useless.  You need to do the bulk of your thread work outside of `Synchronize()`, and then use `Synchronize()` only to perform small updates in the main thread when needed, like displaying status (even then, `Synchronize()` is not always the best choice for that).

Comment: Hi Remy! Do i need simply call loadData() method instead of Synchronize(loadData);

Comment: Yes.  Use `Synchronize()` only when you need to run code in the main thread instead of your worker thread.

Comment: AFAIK Synchronize is used to update the state of VCL components, as I called loadData(); on Execute event, Grid displayed nothing????

Comment: Yes, `Synchronize()` would need to be used to update your Grid when needed.  Not to drive your entire `loadData()` logic as a whole.